# Como cambiar el font-size de un v-label en Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Quiero cambiar el font-size del label de un checkbox pero no logro hacerlo. Agregue una clase, pero no me toma el css. Actualmente mi codigo se ve asi:

```
  <v-flex px-4 xs12 md6>
    <v-checkbox class="captcha"
      v-model="form.iAmNotARobot"
      :label="$t('contact.iAmNotARobot')">
    </v-checkbox>
  </v-flex>
```

y el css

```
   .captcha{
    font-size: 10px!important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta en 2 niveles, por lo tanto debes encadenar las clases para afectar solo al label de ese captcha:

```
.captcha, .v-label  {
  font-size: 40px !important;
}
```